# Why does my Gradle Jenkins plugin try to pass my command line switches before the tasks

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I'm trying to run my tests in Jenkins with Gradle. I have a gradle task called 'test' and I specify which tests to run with --tests

Using the Jenkins Gradle plugin, I've specified the Switches (--tests ) and Tasks ('test') but when the build actually runs it puts the --tests stuff before the tasks which doesn't work at all. I need the task to come first on the commandline before the switches otherwise it doesn't work. What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `--tests` to Tasks in the right order it should work.
I.e. try adding

```
test --tests <test include expression>
```

as Tasks.

Switches is just for convenience - in the end everything will end up as the argument list of the `gradle` executable.